# MySQL replication and ProxySQL

Tags: mysql, replication, proxysql

I just came across ProxySQL. I have one simple question, if I were to use ProxySQL, do I still need to set up Replication(master-slave) first for MySQL server? Because there is hostgroup(`0`,`1`) in ProxySQL which to determine which MySQL server master and slave based on the hostgroups. Or just configure in ProxySQL? Kindly clarify on which steps should I use. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need an existing replication environment since ProxySQL is a proxy service. It can work with Percona XtraDB Cluster, MariaDB Galera cluster or MySQL InnoDB Cluster as well.